netcat fails from one host but suceeds from others all on same network
I am trying to get MaxScale setup on a LAN with three other raspberry pis where I have set each with static ethernet IPs 192.168.0.x via the nmtui tool on an un-managed switch and I am stuck on step 1. NetworkManager is running.
From the the first RPI (IP 192.168.0.1), an RPI 4 running the latest Bookworm OS I get:
# nc -vvvz 192.168.0.2 3306 192.168.0.2: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host (UNKNOWN) [192.168.0.2] 3306 (mysql) open sent 0, rcvd 0
nc -vvvz 192.168.0.3 3306 192.168.0.3: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host (UNKNOWN) [192.168.0.3] 3306 (mysql) : Connection refused sent 0, rcvd 0
nc -vvvz 192.168.0.4 3306 192.168.0.4: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host (UNKNOWN) [192.168.0.4] 3306 (mysql) : Connection refused sent 0, rcvd 0
When I try this from one of the other Pis which are replication servers it succeeds.
nc -vvvz 192.168.0.2 3306 Connection to 192.168.0.2 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!
I can ping and ssh successfully from 192.168.0.1 to the other Pis. Can anyone know how I can get full connectivity for the RPI4 (192.168.0.1)?

try adding -n - e.g. nv -vvvnz - that will remove the warning that otherwise does not effect the connection from taking place

As you have failed to explain how networking is configured or any diagnostics this will at best generate speculative "answers".

@bravo your idea did help. Thank you. Apparently inverse host lookup failed does not mean the connection failed but just that the host could not be "looked up". The connection refused errors were cleared up by adding entries in /etc/hosts and adding permissions in the mariadb servers. Thanks again.

The "inverse host lookup failed" messages are harmless, and you're only getting them because you've specified a high level of verbosity. The reason you get them is because netcat is trying to figure out what hostnames are associated with the IP addresses. The only reason it's doing that is to print more meaningful status/error messages.
In the three instances of netcat that you invoke from 192.168.0.1, the first one, to 192.168.0.2, is successful.
The other two are not, and netcat is reporting a connection refused. This probably means that mySQL isn't running on the other two RPis, or is running but not configured to listen on a network port. Confirm that mysqld is running by checking the output of ps -eaf and check any relevant log files.
Note that alternatively it might mean that the other two RPis have firewalls running which are rejecting incoming traffic. I'm not sure what firewalls management tools are available for Rasperry Pi OS. ufw is typically used on Ubuntu, and firewalld on red hat related systems. Raspberry Pi OS is debian-based, but debian has almost a dozen firewall tools. So you can do a quick check by running sudo iptables-save, although it would help if you were familiar with iptables in order to interpret the output.
(If, instead of getting a connection refused, the connections just hung with no progress for a few minutes, eventually offering a timeout error, I'd assume they were definitely running firewalls. Firewalls configurations sometimes active reject packets, which causes instant connection errors, and sometimes silently drop packets, which causes timeout error after several minutes.)
Edit: fixed parenthetical remark, as I mistakenly flipped the apparent behavior of dropped va rejected packets.
